# Android add onclicklistener to JSONArray gridview

Tags: android, json

I'm very new in android and java.

My JSON had 3 data.

name,
image,
url

I want my fragment which is gridview able to clickable on json array items (click and open the url from url data).

How can I add onclicklistener to array list ?

Below is my code

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //Web api url
    public static final String DATA_URL = "https://www.xxxx.com/test/json.php";

    //Tag values to read from json
    public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "image";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TAG_URL = "url";

    //GridView Object
    private GridView gridView;

    //ArrayList for Storing image urls and titles
    private ArrayList<String> images;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> url;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog while our app fetches the data from url

        //final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait...","Fetching data...",false,false);

        //Creating a json array request to get the json from our api
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Dismissing the progressdialog on response
                        //loading.dismiss();

                        //Displaying our grid
                        showGrid(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        );

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        //Adding our request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }


    private void showGrid(JSONArray jsonArray){
        //Looping through all the elements of json array
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            //Creating a json object of the current index
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                //getting json object from current index
                obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //getting image url and title from json object
                images.add(obj.getString(TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                names.add(obj.getString(TAG_NAME));
                url.add(obj.getString(TAG_URL));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Creating GridViewAdapter Object
        GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(),images,names);

        //Adding adapter to gridview
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_json, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        images = new ArrayList<>();
        names = new ArrayList<>();

        //Calling the getData method
        getData();

        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        return view;


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add the GridViewAdapter class to your post please. what I have done is add a listener to the adapter, and when you call it you implement the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `setOnItemClickListener` to the `GridView`. Inside the `onItemClick` handle the click event when an item is clicked.

See the code below,

```
private void showGrid(JSONArray jsonArray){
    ...
    //Adding adapter to gridview
    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedImage = images.get(position);
            String selectedName = names.get(position);

            // do your stuff here
       } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I try your code but error at (i)

String selectedImage = images.get(i);
String selectedName = names.get(i);